# Residue theorem for circle segments (Anton Deitmar's Automorphic Forms Exercise 1.11)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am currently reading through Anton Deitmar's Automorphic Forms, and he uses the following exercise in a proof of a major theorem.

> **Exercise 1.11** (Residue theorem for circle segments) Let $r_0>0$ and let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<\vert z\vert<r_0\}$, which has a simple pole at $z=0$. Let $a,b:[0,r_0)\rightarrow(-\pi,\pi)$ be continuous functions with $a(r)\leq b(r)$ for every $0\leq r<r_0$ and for $0<r<r_0$  let $\gamma_r:((a(r),b(r))\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ the circle segment $\gamma_r(t)=re^{it}$. Show
> $$
> \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_r}f(z)dz=\frac{b(0)-a(0)}{2\pi}\text{res}_{z=0}f(z)
> $$

I understand the intuition behind this claim that as you shrink to $0$ since you aren't going around an entire loop, you should only get the ratio of how much of the circle is gone around (which explains the $\frac{b(0)-a(0)}{2\pi}$ term). However, I was curious as to what a formal proof of this might look like, I personally tried playing around with "key hole" contours, but I wasn't able to come up with anything substantial. I also searched and was unable to find a proof of this anywhere, but if you know of a reference of this result, I would also find that useful.

Comment: $f=c/z+g$ with $g$ holomorphic hence continuous on the disc; then since the length of $\gamma_r$ shrinks to zero the integral of $g$ (or any continuous function on the disc) goes to zero while for $c/z$ one can explicitly compute the integral and take the limit